# Resistor homework assignment: 7 resistors with connected triangles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: Calculate the equivalent resistance in R]
I am a lost in how to solve this problem, since I don't how where to start. The questions doesn't inform any voltage or current, asking only
the equivalent resistance of the circuit. All resistors have the same resistance: R.

Comment: You could start with Kirchhoff's equations... or a bit of a symmetry argument.

Comment: Grab a multi-meter and some resistors...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the voltage between A and B. The question is all there. @vanger

Comment: The problem is that resistor in the middle, connecting the first triangle to be second. I can't think on how to use Kirchhoff's law here :) @CuriousOne

Comment: Kirchhoff's laws will give you a set of equations for all circuits, no matter how complex. If you can't get to that, then you are not using Kirchhoff's laws. In this case look at the symmetry of the circuit and use the fact that resistors in series are additive to simplify.

Comment: This sort of circuit is most often soluble by looking for symmetry. In this case split that top resistor in two resistors in series of resistance $\frac R 2$ and compare the potential of there node that connects them with the middle node at the bottom. This will enable you to connect an extra wire in the circuit and then it is just parallel and series combinations of resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, you could just write Kirchhoff's equations assuming you know the voltage between A and B. Imagine you are given a two resistors connected in parallel. Then for a given voltage you can express currents through it and resistances using Ohm's law and charge conservation (this's Kirchhoff's equations). So the current would be proportional to a voltage and a coefficient of proportionality would be a total resistance. You can do the same here.

You can also use [star-delta transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform#Basic_Y-.CE.94_transformation) which is a consequence of Kirchhoff's equations and is very convenient here.